# Vue: how to change the style of scoped child components

Tags: css, vue.js, components, styles, vantui

I use vant ui components in vue, like buttons, I want to make a litte changes of it's style, like color, border ...., but I don't how to complete it, anyone could help me solve the problem? Thanks in advance!

I have tried add css or inline-style on element, but don't work!

Answer (score 3):

Any custom `component's` css can be changed by using `deep selector`

GitHub Reference- https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/913

Use `::v-deep` in this case, as `/deep/` will get deprecated.

Reference - [Deep Selector](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors)

Just inspect class of the rendered `element` which you want to modify using `devtools` in chrome or any browser console.

Then, In you consuming `component`, modify it

```
<style scoped>
::v-deep vant-component-class {
   background: red; //
}
</style>
```